# Android market API fails to return results

Tags: android, google-play

I have the below code that gets called in my application. 
the appName passed into the execute method is any app name the user 
wishes to search for. 
initially this worked fine, however now the main app that I want to 
search for are not returning any results. 
for example if appName="maps" an array of values is returned, however 
if appName="capitalOne" no results are found. 
Like I said above this did work and then one day it just stopped 
returning results for the main apps I do searches on. 
any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    private Callback<AppsResponse> callback = new Callback<AppsResponse>() { 
            public void onResult(ResponseContext context, AppsResponse response) { 
                    List<Results> list = new ArrayList<Results>(); 
                    List<App> apps = response.getAppList(); 
                    for (App app : apps) { 
                            Results r = new Results(); 
                            r.setArtistName(app.getCreator()); 
                            r.setArtistId(app.getCreatorId()); 
                            r.setKind(app.getAppType().toString()); 
                            r.setTrackId("DROID_" + app.getId()); 
                            r.setPrice(app.getPrice()); 
                            r.setVersion(app.getVersion()); 
                            r.setAverageUserRating(app.getRating());
                            r.setUserRatingCount(String.valueOf(app.getRatingsCount())); 

                            r.setTrackViewUrl("https://ssl.gstatic.com/android/market/" 
                                            + app.getPackageName()); 
                            list.add(r); 
                    } 
                    res.setResults(list); 
            } 
    }; 
    public T execute(String appName) throws Exception { 
            String query = appName; 
            session.login("email", "password"); 
            res = new SearchResults(); 
            AppsRequest appsRequest = AppsRequest.newBuilder().setQuery(query) .setStartIndex(0).setEntriesCount(10).setWithExtendedInfo(true) 
                            .build(); 
            session.append(appsRequest, callback); 
            session.flush(); 
            return (T) res; 
    }
```

This is the context that is sent to the android market

```
authSubToken: "token goes here"
unknown1: 0
version: 1002012
androidId: "0123456789123456"
deviceAndSdkVersion: "crespo:8"
userLanguage: "en"
userCountry: "us"
operatorAlpha: "T-Mobile"
simOperatorAlpha: "T-Mobile"
operatorNumeric: "310260"
simOperatorNumeric: "310260"
```

Comment: Have you checked if the app still exists? Sometimes people take down apps.

Comment: There is no Android Market API.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/

Answer (score 1):

There is *no official API* for Android Market.

If you're experiencing problems with the third party API, you're using, you should try to contact the developers of that API.

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide you real android id to make it work.
not this fake one androidId: "0123456789123456"

You can obtain it from gtalk service monitor
http://www.honeytechblog.com/monitor-google-talk-service-android/

(number part of android id)

Comment: The fake ID works fine for searching some apps but some it does not.  for example searching for "maps" returns a number of results, however searching for "Capital One" does not return anything.  Additionally I am not working on a real device. this is a fat client java application running on a user workstation not an android device.

Comment: This way is not effective. It is not an official API and it's developers can change or update several time, therefore you will need change your code or approach several time. I created an app with this unofficial API, first time it worked well, then after 1 month crashed, and again became working, then crashed again. And this API can retrieve information not about all applications on the Market. I think that the developers have their own database and they update it when they want. I decided to do not use this API.